# How to get model type in Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding List.cs.t4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Such as the title,How to get model type in Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding List.cs.t4?
get model type fullName also OK.

Comment: I want to get the class attribute of the model class in T4 template.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done to achieve this is to pass the model type as a parameter to the scaffolder, i.e.:

```
Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $outputPath -Template $templateName -Model @{
    ControllerNamespace = $controllerNamespace
    ControllerName      = $ControllerName;
    ModelType           = $ModelType; 
} -SuccessMessage "Added Controller {0}" -TemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Project $ControllerProject -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$overwriteController
```

Then, in my .cs.t4 file, I can use:

```
<#= Model.ModelType #>
```

You could pass any amount of data to your T4 through your PowerShell using this method.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
@model.GetType().Name
```

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: @model can't use in List.cs.t4,this is not the T4 syntax.